# awk or sed etc replace comma with | but where between quotes

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I have a delimited file that I'm trying to replace the commas with an or bar | except where the comma (and other text) is between quotes (")

I know that I can replace the comma using sed 's/,/|/g' filename but I'm not sure how to have the text between quotes as an exception to the rule. Or if it is even possible this easily.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're trying to do "fix" a CSV file that uses quotes around fields containing commas. If so, I recommend that you a scripting language with support for CSV, e.g. python + csv module.

Comment: Provide example input and output in your question please.

Comment: Or re-export your data with the `|` set as field separator. OR look at `csv` specific tools. There are several that get mentioned here all the time. Did you try searching on this topic? Good luck.

Comment: Actually, it is very easy with perl, but you need to know how literal `"` are escaped inside double quoted substrings.

Comment: Take a look at GNU awk and `FPAT`.

Answer (score 0):

As guys recommended here the best and safest is to read csv as csv with appropriate module/library.

Anyway if You wanna sed here it is:

```
sed -i 's/|//g;y/,/|/;:r;s/\("[^"]*\)|\([^"]*"\)/\1,\2/g;tr' file.csv
```

Procedure:

- Firstly it removes any pipes from csv not to corrupt csv.
- Secondly it transforms all commas to pipes
- Thirdly it "recovers" recursively all quoted pipes to commas.

Test:

```
$ cat file.csv
aaa,1,"what's up"
bbb,2,"this is pipe | in text"
ccc,3,"here is comma, in text"
ddd,4,  ",, here a,r,e multi, commas,, ,,"
"e,e",5,first column

$ cat file.csv | sed 's/|//g;y/,/|/;:r;s/\("[^"]*\)|\([^"]*"\)/\1,\2/g;tr'
aaa|1|"what's up"
bbb|2|"this is pipe  in text"
ccc|3|"here is comma, in text"
ddd|4|  ",, here a,r,e multi, commas,, ,,"
"e,e"|5|first column

$ cat file.csv | sed 's/|//g;y/,/|/;:r;s/\("[^"]*\)|\([^"]*"\)/\1,\2/g;tr' | awk -F'|' '{ print NF }'
3
3
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed :

```
sed ':A;s/\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)\([^"]*\)\(,\)/\1|/;tA' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk, `FPAT` and @Kubator's sample file:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^,]+)|( *\"[^\"]+\" *)"  # define the field pattern, notice the space before "
    OFS="|"                          # output file separator
}
{
    $1=$1                            # rebuild the record
}1' file                             # output
aaa|1|"what's up"
bbb|2|"this is pipe | in text"
ccc|3|"here is comma, in text"
ddd|4|  ",, here a,r,e multi, commas,, ,,"
"e,e"|5|first column
```